# How can I execute a script with environment variable and execute with truffle

Tags: javascript, web3js, truffle

I created a script to build hash so I usually executed that like this:

```
$ truffle develop
truffle(develop)> exec scripts/myScript.js
```

but my script now want to read from .env

```
SIGNER= "56443876ca1ea534cc8ddc422f8ab891690325d173916c528d76483681b97fd6"
```

this is my script

```
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "http://127.0.0.1:7545");
console.log('AAA', process.env.SIGNER);
```

I am getting

> AAA undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
$ truffle init test-contract
$ cd test-contract
$ npm init -y
$ npm i web3 --save
$ npm i dotenv --save
```

create a file inside your test folder and write it (test-contract/test/1.test.js) : 1.test.js

```
require("dotenv").config();

const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "http://127.0.0.1:7545");
console.log("AAA", process.env.SIGNER);
```

then create .env file (test-contract/.env) and put following without space :

```
SIGNER="56443876ca1ea534cc8ddc422f8ab891690325d173916c528d76483681b97fd6"
```

finally run the (inside the test-contract folder)

```
$ truffle test
```

result :

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol
> Artifacts written to /tmp/test--11623-Aa2e6hYzLkeX
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.8.10+commit.fc410830.Emscripten.clang

AAA 56443876ca1ea534cc8ddc422f8ab891690325d173916c528d76483681b97fd6


  0 passing (1ms)
```

Comment: does not execute the 1.test.js

Comment: how can i execute 1.test.js?

Comment: the truffle is running the 1.test.js with truffle run. do you put the 1.test.js file inside /test folder?

Comment: before this it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72298515/how-can-i-read-a-file-with-fs-or-without-it-but-i-want-to-read-row-per-row worked good but with your answer no, help me please

Comment: please share your code on an online tools so i'll check it out.